# getting apache ignite continuous query to work without enabling p2p class loading

Tags: ignite

I have been trying to get my ignite continuous query code to work **without** setting the peer class loading to enabled. However I find that the code does not work.I tried debugging and realised that the call to cache.query(qry) errors out with the message "Failed to marshal custom event" error. When I enable the peer class loading , the code works as expected. Could someone provide guidance on how I can make this work without peer class loading? 
Following is the code snippet that calls the continuous query.

```
   public  void subscribeEvent(IgniteCache<String,String> cache,String inKeyStr,ServerWebSocket websocket ){
    System.out.println("in thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-->"+"subscribe event");
     //ArrayList<String> inKeys = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inKeyStr.split(",")));

     ContinuousQuery<String, String> qry = new ContinuousQuery<>();

    /****
     * Continuous Query Impl
     */

    inKeys = ","+inKeyStr+",";
    qry.setInitialQuery(new ScanQuery<String, String>((k, v) -> inKeys.contains(","+k+",")));
    qry.setTimeInterval(1000);
    qry.setPageSize(1);

    // Callback that is called locally when update notifications are received.
  //  Factory<CacheEntryEventFilter<String, String>> rmtFilterFactory = new com.ccx.ignite.cqfilter.FilterFactory().init(inKeyStr);      

    qry.setLocalListener(new CacheEntryUpdatedListener<String, String>() {

          @Override public void onUpdated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends String, ? extends String>> evts) {
            for (CacheEntryEvent<? extends String, ? extends String> e : evts)
            {

                          System.out.println("websocket locallsnr data in thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-->"+"key=" + e.getKey() + ", val=" + e.getValue());
                          try{
                          websocket.writeTextMessage("key=" + e.getKey() + ", val=" + e.getValue());
                          }
                          catch (Exception e1){
                              System.out.println("exception local listener "+e1.getMessage());
                              qry.setLocalListener(null) ;                }

            }

          }
        } );

   qry.setRemoteFilterFactory( new com.ccx.ignite.cqfilter.FilterFactory().init(inKeys));

    try{        

          cur = cache.query(qry);
          for (Cache.Entry<String, String> e : cur)
         { 
           System.out.println("websocket initialqry data in thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-->"+"key=" + e.getKey() + ", val=" + e.getValue());
           websocket.writeTextMessage("key=" + e.getKey() + ", val=" + e.getValue());
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println("exception cache.query "+e.getMessage());

          }        
    }
```

Following is the remote filter class that I have made into a self contained jar and pushed into the libs folder of ignite, so that this can be picked up by the server nodes

```
public class FilterFactory
{

public Factory<CacheEntryEventFilter<String, String>> init(String inKeyStr ){
System.out.println("factory init called jun22 ");

return new Factory <CacheEntryEventFilter<String, String>>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5906783589263492617L;

        @Override public CacheEntryEventFilter<String, String> create() {
            return new CacheEntryEventFilter<String, String>() {
                @Override  public boolean evaluate(CacheEntryEvent<? extends String, ? extends String> e) {
                    //List inKeys = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inKeyStr.split(",")));
                    System.out.println("inside remote filter factory ");
                    String inKeys = ","+inKeyStr+",";

                    return inKeys.contains(","+e.getKey()+",");
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
}
```

Overall logic that I'm trying to implement is to have a websocket client subscribe to an event by specifying a cache name and key(s) of interest.
The subscribe event code is called which creates a continuous query and registers a local listener callback for any update event on the key(s) of interest.
The remote filter is expected to filter the update event based on the key(s) passed to it as a string and the local listener is invoked if the filter event succeeds. The local listener writes the updated key value to the web socket reference passed to the subscribe event code.

The version of ignite Im using is 1.8.0. However the behaviour is the same in 2.0 as well.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the log snippet containing the relevant error

> factory init called jun22 
>   exception cache.query class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to marshal custom event: StartRoutineDiscoveryMessage [startReqData=StartRequestData [prjPred=org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration$IgniteAllNodesPredicate@269707de, clsName=null, depInfo=null, hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2 [rmtFilterFactory=com.ccx.ignite.cqfilter.FilterFactory$1@5dc301ed, rmtFilterFactoryDep=null, types=0], bufSize=1, interval=1000, autoUnsubscribe=true], keepBinary=false, routineId=b40ada9f-552d-41eb-90b5-3384526eb7b9]

Comment: Do you use any specific custom events? Could you please share the full logs?

Comment: Im not using any specific custom events. Im just listening to  org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT. I will provide the logs as an edit to my original question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly deploy you CQ classes (remote filters specifically) on all nodes in topology. Just create a JAR file with them and put into `libs` folder prior to starting nodes.

Comment: Valentin, Thanks for your response. As mentioned in my question, I have exactly done the same. The filter factory code I have posted along with my question was bundled as a self contained jar and copied in to the libs folder of ignite before starting the server nodes. The behaviour is as described in my question.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: As mentioned in my question , it is  class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to marshal custom event: StartRoutineDiscoveryMessage [startReqData=StartRequestData [prjPred=org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration$IgniteAllNodesPredicate@269707de, clsName=null, depInfo=null, hnd=CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2 [rmtFilterFactory=com.ccx.ignite.cqfilter.FilterFactory$1@5dc301ed, rmtFilterFactoryDep=null, types=0], bufSize=1, interval=1000, autoUnsubscribe=true], keepBinary=false, routineId=b40ada9f-552d-41eb-90b5-3384526eb7b9]

Comment: I have uploaded the trace file of the client and can be accessed using https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dux59itbiuJl67SOJfEgRhcqwcycK-BtxXTYc61uei0/edit?usp=sharing . I have highlighted the error message in bold and some key messages.

Comment: Just to add, there are no errors seen in the logs of both the server nodes. The topology is 2 Servers and 1 Client without p2p enabled.

Comment: I'm confused. This message doesn't look like a part of Ignite log. Do you print it out manually? If yes, can you print out not only the error message, but the stack trace as well? There should be a root cause that would tell actual reason of the failure.

Comment: My mistake Valentin. I posted my application log instead of ignite stack trace. My apologies. Here is the updated stack trace of ignite.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dux59itbiuJl67SOJfEgRhcqwcycK-BtxXTYc61uei0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So here comes the cause: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.ccx.ignite.cqfilter.FilterFactory`. Please make sure that `FilterFactory` class implements `Serializable`.

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks ! I still need to figure out why this is not a requirement when p2p is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

From FilterFactory you are returning an instance of an anonymous class which in turn refers to the enclosing FilterFactory which is not serializable.
Just replace the returned anonymous CacheEntryEventFilter based class with a corresponding nested static class.